# How to change upload file location directory? Images is not showing in my admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Guys Actually recently I have installed a source code of the status app with the admin panel. I have installed it successfully but when I try to upload image from the admin panel then it has been upload but it was not showing there. I have checked using inspect element then I found that it is showing a 404 error. And I found that the file is not uploading to the right folder.

When I upload any image and video then it does not show image preview and when I open it in another tab then it is showing a 404 error. Maybe it is an upload directory problem it has the wrong location.

Does anyone know how to change directory location in script?

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTCiX.jpg)

[see image here of 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05d5V.png)

Comment: Please add more information in question. without details no one can understand the issue. show image path. if there is any issue with path or image upload. its not clear from the question

Comment: ok I add more information

Comment: Could you please share some details about your script which is taking care of the file upload and setting the upload path? Do consider that file permissions also play a role.

Comment: @RevealDeal does your code save files to your public directory?

Comment: @RevealDeal, can you plz share some more details like network tab in the element inspect panel? basically I think you do need to check the img file path in the element inspect panel.